# Can VS Intellisense be configured to run "to-cursor"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delphi, intellisense

I use both Delphi and Visual Studio (C#), and I've noticed a difference in how code-completion works which I find really annoying. In Delphi, if you edit existing code so that you change the variable you're using, code completion will give hints based on the code before your cursor. For instance, inserting an "I" into myString to become myIString would give a code hint to show any available variables starting with "myI". Selecting one will then overwrite myString with the new one.

In Visual Studio doing the same thing brings up a code-completion menu with all available variables, and none selected so you see the top of the list. You have to completely delete the variable you're using and start again before you get meaningful code completion.

I seem to make changes like this quite often (maybe I should just get it right in the first place!) so it gets a bit annoying having to remove code, and can be trickier on longer lines with lots of parts to them.

Here's some screenshots which (hopefully) illustrate the difference. I was struggling how best to word this!

[Code completion in Delphi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucmDN.png)

[Code completion in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDVsZ.png)

I've tried playing with the Intellisense settings in Visual Studio and there's nothing there which seems to change the behaviour. Is there any way of replicating it in C#?

Comment: is it `Ctrl` + `Space` what you looking for?

Comment: Ctrl + space brings up the menu you see in the Visual Studio screenshot, but doesn't jump to myInt1, which is the behaviour I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried playing with the Intellisense settings in Visual Studio and
> there's nothing there which seems to change the behaviour. Is there
> any way of replicating it in C#?

For now, VS doesn't support for this behavior. The auto completion won't work when we insert a character into existing variable. It will take effect when we type a character in a empty place.

[image] Type character in a new place, the intellisense works.

[image] Insert character,the intellisense not works.

In my opinion your suggestions is really meaningful. I think it could be better if we have a new option to support for auto-completion when insert character, so I suggest you can Go=>Help=>Seed Feedback=>Provide a suggestion to post your idea there.

We who interested in it will vote for you if you share the link here.

> As alternative ways:

You can go Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C#=>Intellisense=>Enable `Show Completion list after a character is deleted` option.

Then you can insert 'i', the statement could be `myiSring1.GetType();` And delete any or all characters in the `String1`,it would show the intellisense like below:(e.g:I delete 'r'.) Apparently, this is what you really want, but as I mentioned above, VS itself doesn't support this behavior for now, hope you can use 'delete option' saves some time. Sorry for the inconvenience.

[image]

Also, you can check if [ReSharper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JetBrains.ReSharper) can meet your needs,since it's a third-party tool which seems to charge after xx-days trial, I have no further details for it.

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: Thanks @lance-li-msft. Using the "Show Completion list after a character is deleted" option has helped a tiny bit as the code completion menu now jumps to the right place, but I've also added a feedback request as you suggested - see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/575998/allow-intellisense-to-run-to-cursor.html

Comment: Thanks for your help to making visual studio better :)